# SAS Put statement - Why it can be used to convert char to number?

Tags: sas

The code is very simple:

```
data test (keep = state state_num);
set raw1314.accident2013_prf;
  state_num= put(state,z2.);
run;
```

variable "state" contains state names and the output of this program is:

```
  Obs     STATE      state _num
   1      Alabama       01
```

But isn't "put" function is used to convert numerical values into character values? Why it maps "Alabama" to "01" here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second code is the output of the first program, which is the result of "test".

Comment: Does State have a format applied to it and what type is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable STATE must be numeric (1) and have a format applied to it or character (01) with a format applied. If it was the character value of Alabama this would not occur.

```
data _null_;
x=put('Alabama', z2.);
put x;
run;
```

Results:

```
 55         
 56         data _null_;
 57         x=put('Alabama', z2.);
                         ___
                         484
 NOTE 484-185: Format $Z was not found or could not be loaded.

 58         put x;
 59         run;
 Al
```

Comment: Thank you. That's right, the type of "State" is "Num". Then how come a numerical value can be displayed as characters?

Comment: Thats what formats are for, they change how a variable appears in a report or dataset without requiring a new variable to be created.

Comment: I checked the "proc contents". Type = "Num". Format = "STATE13F." Informat = "6". Label = "State Number". I understand that their must be a proc format procedure to change the number into a state name. But then how come the type is still NUM after the change?

Comment: Are you asking about the state or state_num variable? Formats are applies to a variable and they don't change the type of a variable. The variable is still numeric. State_num will be character since it has a leading zero and numbers dont have leading zeroes.